# Creating Database Table From Existing Database Table in progress

Tags: copy, openedge, progress-db

```
create table ABC
( 
 sno integer,
 name character,
 dob Date
 )
```

I have a Database table name ABC.
Now,  I want to create same Database table as name TEST In progress (Openedge).
Can any one help me here to complete this task?

In Oracle:

```
Create Table TEST As Select * from ABC;
```

How to create TEST table in progress OPenedge.

Comment: Are you attempting to use the 4GL (with embedded SQL-89) or the SQL-92 engine?  If you have started a session using "mpro" then it is the 4gl, if you are using sqlexp or some other generic SQL access tool then you are using SQL-92.

Answer (score 2):

1. In Data Administration, go to Admin - Dump Data and Definitions - Data Definitions (.df file).
2. Choose your table ABC and click OK.
3. Enter an output file and choose OK.
4. Open the output file in a text editor (the Progress Procedure Editor will work.)
5. Do a search for "ABC" and replace all instances with "TEST". Save this file.
6. Go back to Data Administration. Choose Admin - Load Data and Definitions - Data Definitions (.df file).
7. Choose your edited file and click OK. The new TEST table should be loaded into the database.

Comment: Be careful with that search and replace - you don't want to accidentally change field names or substrings of keywords etc...

Comment: Good point. Another way to do it is to dump the table schema to a file, rename table "ABC"  to "TEST", then load the dump file to recreate table "ABC". That avoids the search & replace.

Answer (score 2):

OpenEdge SQL also has "CREATE TABLE AS SELECT" syntax. You can use it to create a copy of a table. Example:

```
SQLExplorer>create table pub.custcopy as select * from pub.customer;
SQLExplorer>
SQLExplorer>select top 5 name from pub.custcopy;
Name
----------------------------------------
Lift Line Skiing
Urpon Frisbee
Hoops Croquet Co.
Go Fishing Ltd
Match Point Tennis
```